# Node.js module.exports function with callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function like this:

```
var theThing = fucntion(argumentArray){
    //do the thing
    reutrn resultVar;
}
```

I want to make it a moudle, so I could use

```
var myModule = require('mymodule');
myModule.theThing([arg1, arg2], function(result){
    //handle results
})
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article on just this
http://kevgriffin.com/node-js-using-require-to-load-your-own-files/

Comment: Great article, bookmarked, thanks! But how do I actually handle results via callback?

Comment: create a callback argument in your function and if the argument exists then call that function..

var myFunc = function(a,b,callDude){
//do stuff
if (callDude){
callDude();
}

}

myFunc(4,'cat',done);

done will get fired as it is passed - you choose when to fire done in the function.

Answer (score 1):

In `var theThing = function(argumentArray){`, the function is defined to have **one** argument (an Array value).

In `myModule.theThing([arg1, arg2], function(result){`, the function is called with **two** arguments, an Array and a function.

It seems to be a mistake to define a function with ONE parameter and call it with TWO arguments.